# Why does WITH clauses need to use collect() function?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

## Question

When i got specific nodes by using "WHERE" clauses,
i know to be needed "collect" function.(ex.1 work.)

But i can't understand why "collect" function needed.
(ex.2 don't work.)

ex.1)

```
MATCH (people:PEOPLE) WHERE toInteger(people.age) > 18
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r]-(people)
WITH movie, collect(people) as pe ,count(r) AS rel_num
WHERE rel_num > 2
RETURN movie,pe
```

ex.2)

```
MATCH (people:PEOPLE) WHERE toInteger(people.age) > 18
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r]-(people)
WITH movie, people ,count(r) AS rel_num
WHERE rel_num > 2
RETURN movie,people
```

## My environment

OS:Windows10
Version:    3.2.10
Edition:    Community

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work" ?

Comment: neo4j browser return "(no changes, no records)"

Comment: And also ex.3 return "no changes, no records".

this message mean  syntactic error?

ex.3)

`MATCH (people:PEOPLE) WHERE toInteger(people.age) > 18`
`MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[r]-(people)`
`WITH movie, people, collect(people) as pe ,count(r) AS rel_num`
`WHERE rel_num > 2`
`RETURN movie,pe`

Comment: `no changes, no records` just means that the query returns nothing, but its syntax is correct.  And be careful, you are using an aggregation funciton with an other one. Be sure its the result you want.

Comment: Thank you logisima.
I understood the reason why ex.2 does not work.
But I still can not understand about ex.3.